# Reopened question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, re-open

What was the rationale for reopening <strike>[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/a-binary-quadatic-form-and-an-ideal-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field)</strike> [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198730/notation-for-an-indexed-family-of-sets)? (The initial comments refer to the link that is struck out. But the subject of my query is the other link)

My understanding was that this question was:

- voted closed,
- voted deleted,
- undeleted at the request of the OP
- <strike>voted closed in reaction to the apparent disregard for the previous votes,</strike>
- <strike>reopened, with no visible reason given.</strike>

A recent meta discussion leads me to believe the final action was not done in good faith. But before I form opinions on the incident, I would like to get my facts straight.

Has there been a vote to re-open? Has there somehow been a (subsequently deleted) discussion on the topic of re-opening it during the fairly brief course of events?

Or has action truly been taken with utter disregard for the previous votes? Do I have the wrong post and this was never actually voted closed / deleted? (<strike>was it [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192113/relations-between-fractional-ideals-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field-and) then?</strike> Or another one entirely?) Is there some other case I haven't thought of?

Comment: The (first struck-out) post was closed as "nonconstructive", presumably for the many nonconstructive comments discussing downvotes. These were purged, so there no longer remains anything nonconstructive. What remains is an interesting number-theoretical question, which, if answered, would add great value to the site.

Comment: @Bill: That is a flat out lie. The original voter cited the discussion at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6354/why-was-my-question-about-integral-binary-quadratic-forms-removed as rationale and I concurred. (Unless I have somehow thoroughly mixed up two posts) (P.S. sorry for accidentally deleting my first draft after you commented)

Comment: It is a fact - see the revision history of the question. You have confused two distinct questions.

Comment: Which conveniently excludes the comment history you deleted.

Comment: Dear Hurkyl, since I don't have enough reputation, I can't see deleted comments, so I don't know what could have been said in the deleted comments, but to be honest, I don't see anything wrong with the question at all. In fact, I'm quite shocked that all this fuss has being raised about Bill reopening the question. To me it seems like a well posed question and actually, I would instead ask, what was the rationale for closing the question and downvoting it in the first place?

Comment: @Adrian: That would have been a wonderful question to ask in a meta discussion before reopening it. I find it plausible -- even probable -- that the consensus would be to reopen. But that didn't happen: it was reopened without any input at all. The *apparent* state of affairs is that Bill simply liked the question, so the negative votes and the votes to delete simply didn't matter, and I find that quite distressing.

Comment: @Hurkyl Please get the facts straight. There were no votes to delete. The post was deleted automatically by the SE software because it met some criteria devised by the SE designers to automatically attempt to infer which posts are so worthless that they should be automatically deleted without any human intervention. That failed quite badly here.

Comment: @Bill: There *is* a reason why I *asked* for the facts, y'know, and posted my *understanding* so that it could be corrected. One of the questions involved was asserted to have been voted to delete: was it the other one I linked? Or was it another question that wasn't referenced by title in the previous thread? (I have also been considering later asking a meta question about auto-deletion as well)

Comment: @Hurkyl At the OP's request, I undeleted a few posts that I thought were automatically deleted by the SE software. I had missed the fact that one of them was actually deleted by 20k users, until someone mentioned that on meta. That was not a number theoretical question like the other two but, rather, a soft question on notation/concepts. But even that was not a question of the type that is normally deleted here. In fact there are many analogous questions that haven't even been closed, let alone deleted.

Comment: @Bill: Can you post the link (or explain how I should be able to find it myself)? The main focus of my concern is over that action, or more precisely the follow-up to it. (I had expected the initial undeletion was an oversight of the sort you suggest)

Comment: @BillDubuque, while many such questions «haven't even been closed, let alone deleted», the one you undeleted *was*. This post is about that, precisely: your overriding other users votes to close and to delete. The contrast to your «Let the community make decisions vs. use superpowers» at http://math.stackexchange.com/election/3 is probably part of the discussion, too, btw.

Comment: @Mariano Please get the facts straight. I did not reopen that question. It remains closed.

Comment: You did not reopen the question that «[you] missed the fact that [it had] been actually deleted by 20k users»?

Comment: @Mariano It seems that you are confusing two different questions.

Comment: *See above*, in your comment: I am talking about the same question that you are talking about here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6362/reopened-question#comment22472_6362

Comment: @Mariano I have no clue what you are talking about. But whatever it is did not occur.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You wrote in a comment above « I undeleted a few posts that I thought were automatically deleted by the SE software. I had missed the fact that one of them was actually deleted by 20k users» Honestly, I find this absolutely pointless.

Comment: @Bill: You undeleted a question that was deleted by three users; and you did reopened a post that was closed by five users. **You** alone. If you think something done by a jury of members is incorrect, you should post a meta thread calling for a reconsideration. Matt E could have voiced his opinion, and the posts were likely to be undeleted, reopened, etc. I guess that all users are equally important here, but some users are more equal than others.

Comment: @Mariano Your understanding of the matter is incorrect. You are confusing actions on two different questions

Comment: @Bill: There are three questions acted upon. You are clearly avoiding the real issue here, which is your unilateral actions overriding user-based decisions. Both in undeleting, as well in reopening.

Comment: @Asaf Almost every action taken by moderators is unilateral. As I said, my intent was to reverse the automatic SE deletions. I missed that one was not automatic. I have nothing further to say on these matters beyond what I have said.

Comment: Oh well. Do as you see fit, Bill, as apparently you are right, as usual. For the record, your unilateral use of your *superpowers* to override other users' votes on various instances has my fervent opposition. I walk out of this discussion, and let other users figure out if they are happy with this situation.

Comment: @Mariano How quickly you forget the hundreds (if not thousands) of uses of superpower votes by other moderators (current and past) to close and delete posts, often without any input whatsoever from the community. Thankfully, few (if any) of those votes are from you or I.

Comment: @Mariano, and if users are unhappy? Who can do anything about it? Moderation on the SE network seems to be for unlimited time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You can always write to `team@stackexchange.com`, the SE community team is the correct address if you have a complaint about moderator actions.

Comment: *I* cannot do anything about it, except make it clear that I oppose certain actions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Of course there is something you could do, which is to unilaterally override Bill's actions, as he does to other moderators. (I'm not saying that you should do this, only that you could.)

Comment: @Noah: This is what Gerry pointed as problematic in his recent thread, [A House Divided?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6231/a-house-divided). It is best if the moderators bang things out before they start overriding each other.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I certainly agree with you, but I think it's unfortunate that we're in a situation where one moderator's opinion over-rules all the other moderators.

Comment: @Noah: I **extremely** agree with your last comment.

Comment: @NoahSnyder, well, i was implicitly saying that there is nothing I can sensibly do. I am not going to start doing stupid things to cope with Bill's actions.

Comment: The only thing that "overruled" here was the automatic-deletion algorithm of the SE software.

Comment: And also the three votes to delete; and then another five votes to close a question so its re-deletion could be re-considered.

Comment: @Asaf No, you misunderstand. The question with the 3 votes to delete was *mistakenly* undeleted - due to an oversight I had thought that it too was *automatically* deleted. There was no decision to overrule the votes to delete. The question that got reopened was one that was *automatically* deleted.

Comment: @Bill: Yes. I already understood that there was a human error. The question you have reopened were closed by five people *after* you have undeleted it, in order to allow the community the option to vote for its re-deletion, or allow a fair reopening. *I* believe that the fact that it was automatically deleted was a good enough reason to re-delete it. I am not a big fan of changes, and the status quo was that the question was deleted. You have overridden five people who voted to close while sweeping out all comments without a trace (without even dumping a copy on a meta thread).

Comment: @Bill: Also, you can argue for semantics all you want. If I shoot someone by mistake, I still shot someone. The fact that your mistake has been corrected by Shog *after* you have recognized it is shameful.

Comment: @Asaf Huh? Are you *seriously* going to attempt to argue that those two automatically deleted questions deserve to be deleted?  I don't think you will find *any* community support for that. But if you wish to do so then please do it in a new question to avoid all of the confusion here.

Comment: @Bill: Please stop digressing. I *explained* why I voted to close the undeleted questions. Four more people *agreed* with me on one of the questions. **You** ignored five votes, reopened the question, and deleted all comments without a trace. You should *read* closely my comments instead of assuming you immediately know what I am saying. This seems to be the cause of this entire drama to begin with.

Comment: @Asaf There is no "digression". My comment was a direct reply to your prior strange remark that "I believe that the fact that it was automatically deleted was a good enough reason to re-delete it." Do you wish to retract that statment?

Comment: @Bill: So it is **you** who starts another discussion. Why do you direct *me* to open another thread?? Do it yourself. Let me repeat myself, again, I was explaining *what* closing votes *you* have overridden. If you had bothered to look at the timestamps you would have seen that these votes were made **after** the undeletion.

Comment: @Asaf There is so much confusion here that I don't see anything constructive coming out of further discussion here. If you wish to pursue any of these topics further then I will be happy to join you in a new meta thread - one hopefully free of all the misunderstandings here.

Comment: Your new mantra about confusion is not helping... :-/

Answer (score 13):

Let me give a few points in the history of this meta thread:

1. MK asks three questions; two had a negative sum of votes and automatically deleted, another was closed by five non-moderator users, and then deleted by another three.
2. MK asks "Why was my question deleted?" and Mariano points out that it was an automatic process.
3. Bill takes upon himself to undo the software's action, he undeleted the originally discussed question.
4. MK thanks Bill, and asks for another automatically deleted question to be restored as well.
5. Bill complies. Bill also restores, without being asked to, the third question.
6. When asked whether or not he believes that overriding five closure votes and another three is an act reasonable by a moderator who gives the impression that the community should manage itself, Bill insists that automatic deletion is wrong to begin with.
7. Bill refuses to continue the discussion, Hurkyl gives what I believe a good reason for the restored questions to be closed, and pend their deletion.
8. The first question reopened by Bill, again to the contrary of five members.

What is unclear to me is why a moderator who repeatedly claim that moderators should not act based on *their personal opinion*, acts on his personal opinion, and repeatedly denies users of their vote.  I will not get into a discussion why the question was reopened or undeleted, and whether or not it is right. I just wanted to point out the irony of these actions.

Comment: As you are well aware, there is a *long* history of wrongful downvoting and closure of MK's questions. The matters prompting such behavior have only recently been solved. These questions were on the tail end of such resolution. It is better to let these matters rest. I have nothing more to say on the matter other than what I've already said here and in the parallel meta thread.

Comment: Let us please avoid drama-charged terms like «wrongful»... This is not an Austen novel.

Comment: @Mariano Truth $\ne$ drama.

Comment: @Bill: If that had been given as a rationale, the discussion would have gone quite differently (and possibly more quietly)!

Comment: @Bill: You only provided one reason for these actions, **you** find them right. Not the community, not three or fives *members*. **One** member. I don't recall this community being ran by **you**. You are only a moderator.

Comment: @Bill: One man's truth is another's propaganda. While there may be some kernel of truth in what you assert, there is still some dramatic, even accusatory connotations with the word "wrongful". But you've long demonstrated your firm belief that anyone whose value judgment is not the same as your own is conveniently "wrong", so I wouldn't expect any better of you. So what would you say to a younger and wiser Bill Dubuque who disavowed any and all unilateral moderator action overriding community decisions?

Comment: @Willie To set the record straight, I never "disavowed any and all unilateral actions". Rather, I argued against a *longstanding pattern* of unilateral *closures* and *deletions* that were frequently made by certain moderators (both past and current), often without community input and often disregarding the charter of MSE. Thankfully we are past most of that. And we are almost past all of the problems that sparked this thread. Hopefully we can move on and forgive those who made mistakes, since I don't believe anyone had bad intentions.

Comment: @Bill: You ran on a platform of [Let the *community* make decisions vs. use superpowers.](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-142353), that is a fairly clear message to me. I'm not a native speaker though, so maybe I'm not qualified to read this sentence... If you want to be forgiven for your actions, you can set things right: Delete the question again and ask on meta for it to be reopened by the *community*.

Comment: Dear Asaf, One thing I am confused by: do you think  that the number theory questions of MK should stay deleted, because an automatic software process deleted them?  (I can appreciate that this might be a reasonable person's position, although I don't share it; but I'm not sure if it's actually your position or not.  One point of confusion for me is that the question this post was discussing seemed to change over time, and so it's not always obvious what people are actually objecting to.) Regards,

Comment: @Matt: No. I think that not every question should be automatically undeleted. There are *enough* 10k users now that Bill *should* have posted a link in an answer, and asking members to actively undelete the post[s]. I think that Hurkyl's reasons given in the MK thread comments were excellent. The question *was* deleted, which is enough not to initiate automatic undeletion upon request. When *Bill* did that, and especially his unwillingness to admit a mistake [when I pointed out the third undeletion was unfair] made things *far far worse*.

Comment: @Asaf It may be worth discussing a general policy on undeletion of automatically deleted posts. It is conceivable that this could happen again, and having a policy in place  would help to avoid a repeat of what happened here.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, a general policy would be helpful. But for someone who wishes to let the community govern itself you seem awfully bureaucratic with all these policies.

Comment: The problem with policies is that they enshrine what the current community thinks (well, I say current community - what I *mean* is the 10-20 members who will read the policy and vote on it) without regard to the future community. Is there also going to be a policy of regularly reviewing old policies to ensure that the current set of policies are up to date? (I am being ironic, but only about 50% ironic).

Comment: @Chris: There is actually a policy about being ironic, and it states that you clearly have to be at least 57% ironic. (I am being ironic, or rather ridiculous, 100% :-))

Answer (score 12):

I don't know the particular open/close history of the question, but I can't see any reason why it should be closed (and it is strange that it should have a negative vote total).  It is a perfectly good question in number theory (in fact 
a rather famous one!), and I would certainly vote to reopen it if it were closed.

Added: It seems that the question of MK that my answer responds to (and which was the one originally linked in this post) is in fact not the one that the post intended to refer to.  This is just one reflection of the confusion that seems to be surrounding this issue.

Since I am adding to this answer, let me add a further remark: as far as I can tell, there are three MK questions involved in this discussion, of which two were substantial number theory questions and of which the third (which this post was intended to refer to) was about notation. The third was closed as non-constructive, quite possibly with solid justification.  It seems to have been undeleted by error.  On the other hand, I agree with Bill that the two number theory questions are reasonable, and should not have been deleted.  I understand that they were deleted for reasons related to the automatic functioning of the software, but this seems to me to be akin to a case when an OP's question or answer becomes CW because of multiple edits. Certainly there have been cases when that CW status has been removed by a moderator because they deem it to be inappropriate, despite the software's automatic process; similarly, in this case it would seem to be silly to have  solid number theory questions deleted just because of an automatic process.

Comment: I not really concerned about the actual status of the question, whether deleted or opened, but about the process by which it got there.

Comment: The two SE-automatic deletions that I reversed at the OP's request are [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-ideal-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field) and [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/192113/242) I would be quite surprised if anyone thinks that these questions deserve to be automatically deleted by the SE heuristics on worthless questions, without any human intervention whatsoever.

Comment: Dear Bill: there *was* human intervention. The software only deletes questions which have negative vote count (and which have not been answered)

Comment: No, there was no human intervention on the two questions that I linked to. They were deleted automatically by the SE software.

Comment: ...because they had negative vote totals, which was the 'human intervention' that Mariano was referring to.

Comment: @Chris But those votes were downvotes, not *votes to delete*. None of our users made an *explicit* decision to delete either of those questions. That decision was made by heuristics in some algorithm devised by SE. I agree wholeheartedly with Matt E. that there is no reason that either of those questions should have been closed (let alone deleted), and that it is strange that they had negative vote totals. I'm happy to see that the first post has since received some upvotes. The [second post](http://goo.gl/UcNdM) still needs an upvote to protect it from the SE grim reaper.

Comment: @Bill I realize that they were downvotes, not votes to delete. I was explaining a comment of Mariano's that you seem to have misunderstood.

Comment: @Chris I understood Mariano's comment. But, as I explained, I don't think it is pertinent.

Answer (score 9):

Since Bill hasn't seen fit to answer this question, I will.

Two of Makoto Kato's questions were automatically deleted by the system. MK requested undeletion, and Bill complied. While doing so, he also undeleted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198730/notation-for-an-indexed-family-of-sets), incorrectly believing that it had also been automatically deleted. While Bill feels *personally* that such questions should not be deleted, this particular undeletion was clearly an oversight, and not an attempt to override the wishes of the community.

Given that it was closed (correctly) as Not Constructive, and deleted after a sufficient time for improvement had passed without any edits or efforts to re-open it being made, I've re-deleted it.

Moderators are human. They make mistakes. Fortunately, those mistakes *can* be corrected without ridiculous amounts of drama.

Comment: As far as I can see, MK did not ask for the questions to be undeleted.

Comment: @Mariano: no; he identified two other questions (which were also undeleted, but which had been automatically deleted and had not been closed). So far as I can discern, this particular question was incorrectly identified and incorrectly undeleted. It is regrettable that this mistake was not corrected sooner.

Comment: @Shog: As I wrote to Matt in a comment to my answer, what exacerbated the drama was the fact that Bill were adamant that he did not make any mistakes, and that he is correct. Telling users that he is *unwilling* to discuss anything further, and then deleting the comments and reopening a closed question, seems to me as acts of tyranny.

Comment: @Asaf (1) I've already mentioned a couple times that the 3rd question was mistakenly believed to also have been automatically deleted. That was simply an oversight. I did not immediately reverse that since then most readers would not have been able to read and discuss it here (and see that it was *not* reopened). (2) The reason that I did not intend to address it any further here is due to the fact that this thread is so riddled with misinformation that it seems hopeless to try to get it steered back on course. Instead, I had planned on opening a new meta thread to address these matters.

Comment: @Bill: The facts are that I pointed that out *several* times on the comments to MK's meta thread. You kept insisting otherwise and declared that you will not discuss your actions unless we have a "*reasonable*" reason why the question should be deleted *again*. This is **not** how a moderator should behave. It reminds me a lot more of the times I would argue with my commander during my army service and he ended up pulling rank and telling me "*I just said so, I don't care what you think. Do it my way.*", rather than a conversation with a moderator claiming to be open to suggestions from users.

Comment: @Asaf I did not immediately realize which question you were referring to (nor did the OP here). Originally I thought you were referring to one of the other two automatically deleted questions. Only later did I realize what happened with the 3rd question. Both threads are permeated by misunderstandings throughout. That is why I thought it would be wise to open a new thread.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, there has been *some* confusion. Undeleting on your own accord, with the only reason "I believe this is a good question" is another problem, which Hurkyl addressed. The fact that you reopened a closed question is yet another. Once the question was closed the community could have decided whether or not it wants it reopened or deleted. Your action makes it impossible to let the community take its course. What is interesting is that you rather declare that you essentially remove yourself from discussion than taking a look at what you have done.

Comment: @Shog9 Do questions that are automatically deleted behave any differently from questions deleted by 20K users or moderators? In particular, (how) can the community undelete such automatic deletions? Iirc, content deleted by moderators cannot be undeleted by the community, correct? Knowing such is useful when discussing policy on such matters.

Comment: @Bill: trusted users should be able to undelete automatically-deleted posts. Only moderator-deleted posts are protected from this (this *includes* spam- or offensive-deleted posts, which are additionally locked to prevent ANY modification). For the record, moderators are able to undelete *any* deleted post, an ability they are trusted to use judiciously.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, that's helpful. Readers may recall that [trusted users](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) are those users with 20K+ rep, and they have the ability to vote to delete posts with a score of -1 or lower (it takes 3 such votes to delete a post). We currently have 48 trusted users (not all of which are active on meta).

Comment: @Bill: There are *eight* [non-moderator] trusted users on the front page of the meta users list ordered by participation. I am certain that there are several others which are avid readers, but don't participate often.

Comment: @Asaf: I rarely participate here and don’t read it as a matter of course, but I do keep my eyes open for questions of possible interest to me. Like this one.

Comment: @Shog9: I’ve no problem with the accidental error; it’s Bill’s evasive responses to Mariano and Asaf that I find distressing.

Comment: @Brian If you read all of the comments then you will learn that I had intended to start a new thread to address both the specific and general issues, because this thread is so riddled with misinformation and misunderstanding that I thought it hopeless to try to set matters straight here. The only thing that I was "evading" was all the confusion and misinformation in this thread, which was making it impossible for rational discourse.

Comment: @Bell: I did read all of the comments, here and in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6354/why-was-my-question-about-integral-binary-quadratic-forms-removed) as well. I think that you’re being disingenuous.

Comment: @Brian Your prior comment is a good example of why I wanted to avoid further discussion in *this* thread. All of the misinformation and confusion has led some folks to make false inferences like that. All I can say is that it is most certainly not true.

Comment: @Bill: I am not confused. I made no false inferences. And if you’re not being deliberately disingenuous $-$ and I’m quite prepared to believe that you’re not, just as I believe that you actually do have the best interests of MSE at heart $-$ then you have a somewhat distorted view of your own words in these threads.

Comment: @Brian I can understand why you might feel that way. Certainly I could have handled the matter better. Honestly I never expected a simple oversight to spark such a long confusing thread. I had planned to address the matters in another thread discussing general policy on deletions and undeletions. But before I could do so, I got caught up in trying to correct the many misunderstandings here, and the thread quickly spiraled out of control. Needless to say, I will do my best to avoid the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: Okay, @Bill, let's run a discussion by your rules. When might we see this meta thread you speak of for "address(ing) both the specific and general issues", that is "free of all the misunderstandings here"?

Answer (score 3):

It seems quite clear to me that what Bill actually objects to is *closing questions*, not the means by which they're closed (community, moderator, etc.).

Comment: This could not be further from the truth. Again, *please* refrain from speaking for others. Moreover, the issue here is not *closure* but, rather, the much more extreme action of *deletion*.

Comment: @Bill Noah wrote "It seems [...]", so don't worry that he is speaking for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual subject of my question is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198730/notation-for-an-indexed-family-of-sets) which, while undeleted, was not actually reopened.

Comment: Since that's the question that you intend to refer to, in order to prevent this thread from further spiralling out of control due to further confusion, I struck out the final two bullet items in your question, since they do not apply to this question. The only recent action on that question was that it was undeleted (because I mistakenly thought that it was one of the questions automatically deleted by SE).

Comment: That's fair. I still haven't decided exactly how I wanted to modify my question since I want to consider both the question I originally linked and the one I intended to refer to, and that's as good as any for now.